# Javascript API for formatting dates in 2013

Tags: javascript

I've noticed that SharePoint 2013 uses past tense time periods for a lot of it's date formatting. eg

- A few seconds ago
- Yesterday at 3:00pm
- 5 days ago
  etc.

Is there a JavaScript method available that takes a date and returns that type of format?

Answer (score 1):

Not in 2010 and haven't found one in 2013 (yet). The method SP uses to generate the formatting is SPUtility.TimeDeltaAsString(). I've Reflector in that method in 2010 and it seems to be fairly straight forward if I was to do a JavaScript implementation. Maybe the same approach would work in 2013?

Answer (score 1):

When I worked with ClientContext I got dates in form of `Date`.
You could use any library that works on that, such as http://momentjs.com .

```
var c = new SP.ClientContext();
var w = c.get_web();
c.load(w);
c.executeQueryAsync(function() {
    var created = moment(w.get_created()).fromNow();
    // "6 months ago"
    console.log(created);
});
```

Comment: I had originally deleted this post because I realized it does not correctly answer @paul-lucas question. But it might still be interesting to see how to get dates the other way around, as well as considering fetching dates through ClientContext when they are hard to parse. Moments does not support parsing of 'Timeago'

Answer (score 1):

I haven't seen this javascript code in sharepoint javascript API. I would like to recommend [moment.js](http://momentjs.com) a lightweight javascript library for date and time handling in javascript which can show relative time as well